# proper way to stop a daemon process

Tags: python, process, daemon

I have a Jython script that I run as a daemon.  It starts up, logs into a server and then goes into a loop that checks for things to process, processes them, then sleeps for 5 seconds.

I have a cron job that checks every 5 minutes to make sure that the process is running and starts it again if not.

I have another cron job that once a day restarts the process no matter what.  We do this because sometimes the daemon's connection to the server sometimes gets screwed up and there is no way to tell when this happens.

The problem I have with this "solution" is the 2nd cron job that kills the process and starts another one.  Its okay if it gets killed while it is sleeping but bad things might happen if the daemon is in the middle of processing things when it is killed.

What is the proper way to stop a daemon process... instead of just killing it?

Is there a standard practice for this in general, in Python, or in Java?
In the future I may move to pure Python instead of Jython.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the daemon's connection to the server sometimes gets screwed up"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a `SIGTERM` first before sending `SIGKILL` when terminating the process and receive the signal by the Jython script.

For example, send a `SIGTERM`, which can be received and processed by your script and if nothing happens within a specified time period, you can send `SIGKILL` and force kill the process.

For more information on handling the events, please see the [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module documentation.

Also, example that may be handy (uses `atexit` hook):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from signal import signal, SIGTERM
from sys import exit
import atexit

def cleanup():
    print "Cleanup"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from time import sleep
    atexit.register(cleanup)

    # Normal exit when killed
    signal(SIGTERM, lambda signum, stack_frame: exit(1))

    sleep(10)
```

Taken from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/533117-cleaning-up-when-killed/).

Answer (score 0):

The normal Linux type way to do this would be to send a signal to your long-running process that's hanging. You can handle this with Python's built in signal library.

http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html

So, you can send a SIGHUP to your 1st app from your 2nd app, and handle it in the first based on whether you're in a state where it's OK to reboot.

Comment: Thanks!  petr's example "just works" but I'll refer to that documentation if I run into problems or if I get bored ;-)